# gitk gives "can't read "git_version": no such variable" and won't run

Tags: git, gitk

Today gitk stopped working.  When I try to run it (with or without `--all`), it says this:

```
Error in startup script

can't read "git_version": no such variable
    while executing
"package vcompare $git_version "1.6.6.2""
    invoked from within
"if {[package vcompare $git_version "1.6.6.2"] >= 0} {
    set show_notes "--show-notes"
}"
    (file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\gitk" line 12225)
```

This started when working with a repository where I couldn't fetch commits (from BitBucket) due to what appeared to be a corrupted object.  But I was able to clone the repository again, and now I have that commit and others after it.

I'm not certain that's related, though, because gitk has the problem above in *any* repository.

How can I fix this?

Things I've tried:

- Uninstall and reinstall Git.  (Both with and without wiping out settings completely.)
- Hacking at the Tcl script in gitk, changing all the version checks to `if {1}` and changing one version check line to a hard-coded:

  `regexp {^git version ([\d.]*\d)} "1.9.5" _ git_version`

  After doing that, I can get gitk to *run*, but there's no commit history; it just says "No commits selected".
- Getting the [very latest version of gitk](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/gitk-git/gitk) and copying it over my existing gitk.  Exact error message (except the line number, but it's the same actual line of code).
- I don't usually use Git GUI, but if I try it (`git gui`), it fails with a similar message:

  > git-gui: fatal error
  >
  > Cannot parse Git version string:
- But if I do a regular `git version`, I get:

  > git version 1.9.5.msysgit.1

Comment: Are you sure that your hard drive is OK if you first encounter a corrupted object and then find some application not working?

Comment: @martin, well, I haven't encountered any other anomalies.  And it's not clear that the two problems are related.  And I can get gitk to *run* with the hacks noted above; it just doesn't do anything useful then.  Granted, my work computer *is* absolute garbage, but in four years of working with Git I've never seen this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that these problems resulted from a change of my user directory, owing to some Active-Directory-related changes on my work network.

If you run into similar problems, see whether your user directory has moved around or become inaccessible, preventing Git from accessing global settings.